# What's the meaning of 'or else' here? Does it present a third alternative?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Theology is parasitic upon religion. If there were no religious faith, there would be
>   no theology. It would therefore be absurd to suggest that there is not or should not
>   be a close connection between faith and theology. Moreover it is grossly misleading
>   to suggest that an attitude of no faith represents a desirable position of neutrality.
>   Absence of faith arises either from *lack of interest in or attention to the subject* (and
>   it is difficult to regard that as an essential precondition for being a good scholar of
>   the subject) **or else** *it represents one particular standpoint comparable with the
>   standpoint of faith.*

Am I right that [ODO's Definition 1(.0)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/or-else?q=or+else) applies?

> **or else** = 1. Used to introduce the second of two alternatives

The italicised last independent clause '*it represents ...
standpoint of faith* sounds like a general indefinite, hazy claim that comprises two nouns (as a disjunt) already 'lack of interest in or attention to the subject', so to what's it an alternative? The definition above doesn't allow a third alternative?

Comment: The passage is poorly written and muddled. A waste of time trying to parse it.

Answer (score 3):

As DamkengT says, there are two alternatives here. But one of them has two parts.

You might think of it like this:

Alternative 1: lack of something

Alternative 2: one particular standpoint

But then 1 has two parts, so:

1a: lack of interest
1b: lack of attention
2: one particular standpoint

That said, I find the paragraph a little muddled. How is "one particular standpoint" the opposite of "lack of interest" in this context? Perhaps if I read the following text it would be clear.

By the way, "or else" doesn't necessarily introduce the second of two alternatives. It could introduce any of a list of alternatives. It is quite reasonable to say, "You can get a blue one, or a green one, or else you can get a red one." i.e. here it is the third of three. Or "You can get a blue one, or else you can get a green one, or you if you prefer you can get a red one." There it introduces the second of three. Etc.

Comment: +1 I agree about the use of "or else" with more than two alternatives. It's only natural. Though defining "or else" as a phrase for the second of two alternatives is not really technically wrong, in my opinion, because we can group everything before "or else", no matter how many things linked with "or", as just one thing. The OP's example doesn't have that many alternatives, in any case.

Comment: Consider this: “On a warm but rainy day in summer, you can wear a raincoat or carry an umbrella, or else you can go outside wearing only your swimsuit.” From a purely mechanical analysis, it looks like three alternatives, but if you think about it, you can see that it’s **1a** and **1b** (protect yourself against the rain) versus **2** (expose yourself to the rain).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see it as three alternatives.

To illustrate the two alternatives I see, here is the sentence in question,

> *Absence of faith arises either from lack of interest in or attention to the subject (and it is difficult to regard that as an essential precondition for being a good scholar of the subject)*
>   ***or else***
>   *it represents one particular standpoint comparable with the standpoint of faith*.

In short, the writer proposes two propositions. If it's not the first, it has to be the second.

Comment: Yes, option 1 is "a lack" (and the thing lacking is either "interest" or "attention"), and option 2 is "it represents a standpoint".